# The world ............. a new era

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Which verbs can be used in the blank in the following sentence?

> The world  ............. a new era.

Especially are the following sentences are correct? Would there a difference between them if all are acceptable choice?

1.The world  came into a new era.

2.The world  moved to a new era

3.The world  entered (into) a new era.

Comment: 1. and 2. are past tense; that means 3. should be *entered*, not *enter*.

Comment: @Glorfindel Why do you think any results do not show up when I search "world came into a new era" on Google.

Comment: I have no idea. I am not Google :)

Answer (score 1):

All three can be correct, depending on what you want to say.  Remember how English speakers use "go" and "come" to reflect not only direction of movement but also the speaker's *viewpoint* -- I can say "Please come to my house this evening," even if I am not at home, to reflect the *view* of us, together at my house.  It sounds *warmer* and more like an *invitation* than, "Please go to my house this evening," which sounds like a *request* or even an *order*.

In the same way "the world came into a new era (with ...)" suggests a sense that I, the speaker, and you, the reader, are part of "the world".  Meanwhile "the world *moved* into a new era" takes us both *outside* the world, as if the movement is happening to someone else.

"The world entered a new era ..." is (at least to my ears) similar to "came into" -- it brings both of us into the action. In addition it emphasizes the nuance of a "new beginning", and has some elements of *optimism* and *approval*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why do you think any results do not show up when I search "world came into a new era"  on Google. Does it sound too informal for the context so that people do not use it?

Comment: I suppose the phrasing is awkward.  It's not something I would use, although it would be understood.  Instead I would say "entered" or that someone *brought* the world into a new era or possibly an entirely different metaphor.